# MP4Box Multiple representations causing error

Tags: audio, stream, mp4

I'm trying to create a dash file with three representations using mp4box however upon creating the file I have tried to validate it and received this

```
    <svrl:failed-assert test="if (not(@duration) and not(child::dash:SegmentTimeline)) then false() else true()"
location="/*[local-name()='MPD' and namespace-uri()='urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011']/*[local-name()='Period' and namespace-uri()='urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011']/*[local-name()='AdaptationSet' and namespace-uri()='urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011']/*[local-name()='SegmentTemplate' and namespace-uri()='urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011']">
```

If more than one Media Segment is present the duration attribute or SegmentTimeline element shall be present.

Does anyone know what Might be causing this? The stream does play with my application for whats it's worth..

Answer (score 0):

Without the command line you used, the exact version of MP4Box you used, and the full MPD and/or media, it's hard to determine what went wrong. The sentence you quote is indeed part of a conformance check from the MPEG DASH conformance standard. It may be a bug with MP4Box, but it may also have been fixed already. I suggest you file an issue [here](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues) giving as much information as possible.