# How do I pseduo live-stream video using DASH non chronologically?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I want to stream a local mp4 file to the DASH.js html5 player, but I want don't want to play this mp4 file chronologically. My requirement is that I create a never ending video stream from a single mp4. I figure that this is best done server side within the creation of the MPD manifest file. I don't know how to achieve this though. I believe that [this stream](http://vm2.dashif.org/livesim-dev/segtimeline_1/testpic_2s/Manifest.mpd) demonstrates the wrapping behaviour.

*How do I generate a manifest similar to this stream, and how do I format my mp4 correctly to achieve this?*

I have tried making a server that intentionally sends the wrong segments but this causes playback to fail. I have also attempted to create a live stream MPD manifest using MP4Box but this also causes playback to fail.

```
mp4box -dash 1000 -profile dashavc264:live -dynamic -out DASH.mpd -mpd-duration 0 -mpd-refresh 10 -time-shift 0 -min-buffer 5 vid.mp4#video vid.mp4#audio
```

This produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.6.2-DEV-rev636-g4bd31f8-ab-suite   at 2016-07-05T14:20:26.756Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT0.005S" type="dynamic" publishTime="2016-07-05T14:20:26Z" availabilityStartTime="2016-07-05T14:20:26.756Z" timeShiftBufferDepth="PT0H0M0.000S" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT0H0M10.000S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M1.001S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011,http://dashif.org/guidelines/dash264">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.io">
  <Title>DASH.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period id="GENID_DEF" start="PT0H0M0.000S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="24000/1001" par="16:9" lang="und">
    <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc3.64001f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="24000/1001" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="1428068">
    <SegmentTemplate timescale="24000" media="vid_dash_track1_$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="24000" initialization="vid_dash_track1_init.mp4"/>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="eng">
   <Representation id="2" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="32000" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="97557">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
    <SegmentTemplate timescale="32000" media="vid_dash_track2_$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" duration="32000" initialization="vid_dash_track2_init.mp4"/>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

The HTML5 player won't play any content, however, it will attempt to refetch the manifest in the correct manner. I'm not really sure what is going wrong, and what I need to do to replicate the stream above.

Comment: Using the command 

`mp4box -dash 30000 -frag 30000 -frag-rap -profile dashavc264:live -dynamic -mpd-refresh 5 -segment-timeline -url-template -out dash.mpd vid.mp4#video vid.mp4#audio` 

I was able to produce a result similar, but I still can't get this manifest to load in chrome.

Comment: Checking the XML over [here at the dash XML validator](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=605) shows that the output isn't valid. 'If more than one Media Segment is present the duration attribute or SegmentTimeline element shall be present.' It appears to be related to [this report](https://sourceforge.net/p/gpac/discussion/287547/thread/e701af11/?limit=25) and this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659253/mp4box-multiple-representations-causing-error). I am using multiple representations since the dashIF player requires it.

Answer (score 1):

-time-shift needs to be set to a value higher than 0. E.g., set it to 60.

It means the available time of each segment after it is streamed.